# Use gradle to execute webpack which is not in the root directory of project

Tags: java, gradle, webpack

The structure of my project is similar to the following:

```
-- root
  -- gradlew
  -- build.gradle
  -- src
     -- main
       -- frontend
          -- webpack.config.js
          -- package.json
          -- src
          -- node_modules
       -- java
       -- resources
          -- static
```

I'd like to get gradle run the `webpack.config.js` located inside the `root/src/main/frontend` folder, and write it to `bundle.js` in `src/main/java/resources/static`. I tried this script:

```
task myNpmInstall(type: NodeTask) {
    args = ['install']
    inputs.file file('src/main/frontend/package.json')
    outputs.dir file('src/main/frontend/node_modules')
}

task webpack(type: NodeTask, dependsOn: 'myNpmInstall') {
    script = file('src/main/frontend/node_modules/.bin/webpack')
}

processResources.dependsOn 'webpack'
```

This is a part of my `package.json`:

```
  "engines": {
    "npm": "5.5.1",
    "node": "8.9.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "node ./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js",
    "test": "mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register --require ./test/test_helper.js --recursive ./test",
    "test:watch": "npm run test -- --watch"
  },
```

and this is the `webpack.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: [
    './src/index.js'
  ],
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel-loader'
    }]
  }
};
```

I get this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Required script property is not set.
```

I noticed that even when I run `./gradlew myNpmInstall` I get the same error. How can I fix this ?

**Update 1**
I updated the gradle file content to

```
node {
    version = '8.9.1'
    npmWorkDir = file('src/main/frontend')
    nodeModulesDir = file('src/main/frontend')
    download = true
}

task webpack(type: NodeTask, dependsOn: 'npmInstall') {
    script = file("$projectDir/src/main/frontend/node_modules/.bin/webpack")
}

processResources.dependsOn 'webpack'
```

and now I get this error:

```
No configuration file found and no output filename configured via CLI option.
A configuration file could be named 'webpack.config.js' in the current directory.
Use --help to display the CLI options.

Execution failed for task ':webpack' Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/home/arian/workspace/myproj/.gradle/nodejs/node-v8.9.1-lin‌​ux-x64/bin/node'' finished with non-zero exit value 255
```

Comment: What is NodeTask?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all here is [com.moowork.node docs](https://github.com/srs/gradle-node-plugin/blob/master/docs/node.md) 
You can specify project location with `nodeModulesDir`

```
node {
    download = true
    // Set the work directory where node_modules should be located
    nodeModulesDir = file("${project.projectDir}/src/main/frontend")
}
```

`NodeTask` is used to run something like `./node script`. That is why it complains that `Required script property is not set.`. But usually what you really want is to run yarn/npm task declared in `package.json`

I prefer to use `YarnTask`, because it feels faster for me

```
task webpack(type: YarnTask, dependsOn: yarn) {
    args = ['build-spring'] 
    // 'build-spring' is script in your package.json you want to run
}
```

For npm it would look something like

```
task webpack(type: NpmTask, dependsOn: npmInstall) {
    args = ['run','build-spring']
}
```

Comment: @ArianHosseinzadeh yeah, but why do you run `NodeTask` if you actually want to run some task in your `package.json` you should run `NpmTask` or `YarnTask` `NodeTask` is for something like `./node script`, do you really want it? If yes, then why?

Comment: Thanks ! it worked. You are right, `NodeTask` needs script, while I have `build` setup in my `package.json`

Comment: Do I need to keep `processResources.dependsOn 'webpack' `?

Comment: @ArianHosseinzadeh it will run `webpack` task with each gradle build so i usually enable it only for production and debug client and server side separately. [Docs](https://github.com/srs/gradle-node-plugin/blob/master/docs/faq.md#how-to-avoid-nodenpmyarn-task-execution-if-no-changes-in-web-files) says that you can setup "to avoid node/npm/yarn task execution if no changes were made" , but i never used it.

Comment: It looks like the provided plugin has been deprecated. This one seems to be the recommended alternative: https://github.com/node-gradle/gradle-node-plugin

Answer (score 1):

Try to add configuration section to node:

```
node {
    version = '6.11.0'
    npmWorkDir = file('src/main/frontend')
    nodeModulesDir = file('src/main/frontend')
    download = true
}
```

And with `node` plugin you will already have `npmInstall` task, so you could remove task `myNpmInstall`

See [examples](https://github.com/srs/gradle-node-plugin/tree/master/examples)

Comment: I get this error now:
`org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':webpack'`
`Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/home/arian/workspace/myproj/.gradle/nodejs/node-v8.9.1-linux-x64/bin/node'' finished with non-zero exit value 255`
(I had to change the node version, I get the same error with version you suggested, so it is not related to the version)